# What are the possible values for the algebraic multiplicies?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose there is a matrix $A_{4\times 4}$ with two distinct, real eigenvalues. What could the algebraic multiplicities of these eigenvalues be?

I'm not really sure how to go about answering this. I would assume the answer would just be $(2,2)$ and $(1,3)$, but what are some examples where these would be the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the answers.  Some examples:
$$
\pmatrix{1\\&1\\&&0\\&&&0}, \pmatrix{1\\&0\\&&0\\&&&0}
$$